# To BLOB or not to BLOB

Tags: mysql, blob, innodb

I am in the process of writing a web app backed up by a MySQL database where one of the tables has a potential for getting very large (order of gigabytes) with a significant proportion of table operations being writes.  One of the table columns needs to store a string sequence that can be quite big.  In my tests thus far it has reached a size of 289 bytes but to be on the safe side I want to design for a maximum size of 1 kb.  Currently I am storing that column as a MySQL MediumBlob field in an InnoDB table.

At the same time I have been googling to establish the relative merits and demerits of BLOBs vs other forms of storage.  There is a plethora of information out there, perhaps too much.  What I have gathered is that InnoDB stores the first few bytes (789 if memory serves me right) of the BLOB in the table row itself and the rest elsewhere.  I have also got the notion that if a row has more than one BLOB (which my table does not) per column then the "elsewhere" is a different location for each BLOB.  That apart I have got the impression that accessing BLOB data is significantly slower than accessing row data (which sounds reasonable).

My question is just this - in light of my BLOB size and the large potential size of the table should I bother with a blob at all?  Also, if I use some form of inrow storage instead will that not have an adverse effect on the maximum number of rows that the table will be able to accommodate?

MySQL is neat and lets me get away with pretty much everything in my development environment.  But... that ain't the real world.

Comment: If you want to store String you should use TEXT instead of the blob so that your String would be properly encoded / decoded

Comment: Also, a 1000-byte text column is not something you should worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've already looked [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) but it's easy to overlook some of the details since there is a lot to keep in mind when it comes to InnoDB limitations.

The easy answer to one of your questions (maximum size of a table) is 64TBytes. Using variable size types to move that storage into a separate file would certainly change the upper limit on number of rows but 64TBytes is quite a lot of space so the ratio might be very small.

Having a column with a 1KByte string type that is stored inside the table seems like a viable solution since it's also very small compared to 64TBytes. Especially if you have very strict requirements for query speed.

Also, keep in mind that the InnoDB 64TByte limit might be pushed down by the the maximum file size for the OS you're using. You can always link several files together to get more space for your table but then it's starting to get a bit more messy.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I had come across the article you mention but had missed the bit about rows less than half page size being stored locally.

Comment: @DroidOS Glad I could help. And yes, there are lots of details to keep in mind, just as I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

if the BLOB data is more then 250kb it is not worth it. In your case i wouldn't bother myself whit BLOB'n. [Read this](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)